# I'm confused on how to do OR while do Boolean. "||" that won't work for me for some reason

Tags: c++, cmath

here is my code. I want my if statement to work if the user types in Yes or yes. When I take out || and the "yes" My program works fine and when the user types in "Yes" it works. I wanted to make my program better and also have it so that when they type in "yes" to work. Can someone help me figure this out? Thanks!

```
{

    cout<<"Would you like to begin?\n";


    cin>>answer;

    if (answer=="Yes" || "yes") {

        continue_1=true;

        google=false;

    }

    else {

        if (answer=="No" || "no" ) {

            cout <<endl<< "have a nice day\n";

            google= false;

            return 0;

        }
```

Comment: Is nobody going to mention `stricmp`?

Comment: also, some `tolowercase` thing, instead of multiple checks.

Comment: Guys, stop posting answers. It's embarrassing.

Comment: Also, stop assuming `std::string`.

Comment: I don't know why the downvotes, this is a classic beginner's problem clearly explained.

Comment: @SList Good point. But this problem is posted about once a day.

Comment: So let's mark it as duplicate then.  (Too much C# programming here, I have pulled my answer...)

Comment: @SList It's hard to find the duplicates since their titles have nothing to do with the mistake. My point is that SO-people seem to be tired of people that post here before finishing reading a basic tutorial

Comment: People can read tutorials and still be blind stuck with simple errors when they are beginners.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing the or on the strings, not on the query - you want:

```
    if (answer=="No" || answer=="no" ) {
```

To be more generic about it though you could convert the string to lowercase and then compare that with "no", which will handle "No", "NO" and "no" for you.

Quite a common alternative approach is to just check that the first character in the string is either N or n. That also picks up things like Nope, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (answer=="Yes" ||  answer == "yes")
```

You need to use the `==` in both checks. Unfortunately it doesn't work otherwise

Comment: It's not so much unfortunate as it is about how booleans are created. I'm not sure it'd do us any good to treat this as a special case.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ I agree, I was more or less being sarcastic... Or as in the case of the OP it was unfortunate because it caused him to be stuck for quite a while apparently :)

Answer (score 1):

Where does one start?

Precedence - see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence
String comparison = See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

And learn about pointers

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
if (answer=="Yes" || answer=="yes")
```

It doesn't carry anything from the first side, OR's and AND's can be used to mix different values. like this:

```
if (answer=="Yes" || otherAnswer=="no")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather do it with less branching:

```
cout<<"Would you like to begin?\n";
cin>>answer;

if (answer== "No" || answer== "no")
  return 0;

if (answer!= "Yes" && answer!= "yes" )
  return error; // only answer with yes or no

// here, we know that the answer is yes
```